# Bootstrap THEME_menu_tree() on a new menu

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and the [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). In the template.php file, I am successfully theming the primary menu (main menu) to enable extra list styles with the following code.

```php
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__primary($variables) {
  return '<ul class="custom-style">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

I would also like to theme a new menu (menu-banner), but I can't access it as expected, with the following code.

```php
function MYTHEME_menu_tree__menu_banner($variables) {
  return '<ul class="custom-style">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

The new menu is successfully defined in `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()` in the template.php file.

```php
$menu = menu_navigation_links('menu-banner');
$vars['banner_nav'] = theme('links__menu_banner', array('links' => $menu));
```

I'm able to render it as *banner_nav* in the page templates.

Is there something I'm missing, or is there something specific to Bootstrap that is different from what reported from [`theme_menu_tree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to Bootstrap. In your preprocessor you're using `theme_links`, which is unrelated to menus. Your "menu" isn't being output as a menu at all.

If page preprocessing is necessary, you can try:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $menu = menu_tree_all_data('menu-banner');
  $vars['banner_nav'] = menu_tree_output($menu);
}
```

Or you can render the menu block (these are automatically generated if you have the Blocks module enabled):

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $block = block_load('menu', 'menu-banner');
  $vars['banner_nav'] = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
}
```

In page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($banner_nav); ?>
```

Either will work.

If you don't need to preprocess the menu, you can simply position it via the Blocks admin UI.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!, I'll give it a go.

In the meantime, I was able to get it working using the secondary navigation instead of a custom menu, which is good sort of.

My main motivation with this is to get to a place where I can re-use classes instead of having a ziggurat of rules for similarly styled things like menus that are mostly the same design.